# How to add OnItemClickListener on my CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm in a bind here, I wanted to integrate OnItemClickListener in my CustomAdapter, so when an item is click, it'll show some message or something. But I am not sure where to set it. I've look at bunch of tutorials and some post here but it only make me more confuse. So I need guidance on how and where would I need to set it to make it work. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
ListView listView;
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
new ReadRSS(MainActivity.this, listView, "http://malaysiakini.com/en/news.rss").execute();
```

ReadRSS.java

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    //Dismiss progress dialog
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();



    if (feedItems != null) {
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context,R.layout.activity_listview,feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }     

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItem> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FeedItem> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
    }

    FeedItem p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getPubDate());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is not the direct answer to your question, but my own code example so you can have a look at it and get the idea;

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listword,R.id.wordView1, companies);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.secondListView1);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Item Click listener

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ok, View v, int position, long id){

          // Do your stuff here

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set it inside the adapter, but inside your activity where you define you ListView :

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
new ReadRSS(MainActivity.this, listView, "http://malaysiakini.com/en/news.rss").execute();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this,hope it helps:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItem> implements OnClickListener{
    private Context mContext;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FeedItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
          mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
        }

        FeedItem p = getItem(position);
        v.setTag(p);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
            }

            if (tt2 != null) {
                tt2.setText(p.getPubDate());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        FeedItem p = (FeedItem) v.getTag();
        // TODO,do something with p and mContext
    }

}
```

But I think you should use `listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener)` to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform task on individual component of CustomAdapter class. Check below code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItem> {
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FeedItem> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

{

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
    }

    FeedItem p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getPubDate());
        }
        tt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform your task

        });
        tt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform your task

        });


    }

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code on your activity below of your set adapter method.

**Set Adapter Method**

```
private void setAdapter() {
    try {
        DoctorAppointmentListAdapter doctorAppointmentListAdapter = new DoctorAppointmentListAdapter(getContext(), doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList, selectedItemClickListener, screen);
        appointmentListView.setAdapter(doctorAppointmentListAdapter);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

**Costume Click Methods**

```
//ListAdapter Click Listener
DoctorAppointmentListAdapter.SelectItemClickListener selectedItemClickListener = new DoctorAppointmentListAdapter.SelectItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemClickedAtIndex(int index, String operation) {
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("00")) {
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
            viewDetailsScreen(index);
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("11")) {
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
            //Video Call Operation
            patirntId = doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_patient_id();
            videocallService(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_patient_id(), doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_id());
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("33")) {
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
            //Video Call Operation
            patirntId = doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_patient_id();
            videocallCompletedService(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_patient_id(), doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getAppointment_id());
        } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("22")) {
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
            //Phone Call Operation
            if (doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getPatient_contact_no().length() > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(index).getPatient_contact_no()));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
};
```

**This is Adapter Class**

```
 public class DoctorAppointmentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private Context context;
private int screen;
private ArrayList<DoctorAppointmentObject> doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList;
private SelectItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public DoctorAppointmentListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DoctorAppointmentObject> doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList, SelectItemClickListener listener, int screen) {
    this.context = context;
    this.screen = screen;
    this.doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList = doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    try {
        if (itemClickListener != null) {
            itemClickListener = null;
        }
        itemClickListener = listener;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public interface SelectItemClickListener {
    public void itemClickedAtIndex(int index, String operation);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView doctorNameTextView, numberTextView, datetimeTextView, enteryTextView;
    private TextView viewDetailTextView, videoCallTextView, phoneCallTextView;
    private CircleImageView profile_image;
    private ImageView onlineStatusImageView;
    private CircularProgressView progress_view;
}

ViewHolder holder = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_doctor_appointment_list, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.doctorNameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.doctorNameTextView);
        holder.numberTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
        holder.datetimeTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.datetimeTextView);
        holder.enteryTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.enteryTextView);

        holder.viewDetailTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.viewDetailTextView);
        holder.videoCallTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.videoCallTextView);
        holder.phoneCallTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.phoneCallTextView);


        holder.profile_image = (CircleImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        holder.progress_view = (CircularProgressView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_view);

        holder.onlineStatusImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.onlineStatusImageView);
        holder.onlineStatusImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (screen == 1) {
        holder.videoCallTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getPatient_profile_pic()).into(holder.profile_image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                holder.progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        holder.progress_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.doctorNameTextView.setText(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getPatient_display_name());
    holder.numberTextView.setText(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getPatient_contact_no());

    if (doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getAppointment_time().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        holder.numberTextView.setText("");
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getAppointment_time());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        holder.numberTextView.setText("" + newFormat);
    }
    holder.datetimeTextView.setText(doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getAppointment_reason());
    if (screen==0){
        holder.enteryTextView.setText("Entry Time :" + doctorAppointmentObjectArrayList.get(i).getAppointment_entry_time());
    }else {
        holder.enteryTextView.setText("");
    }

    holder.viewDetailTextView.setId(i);
    holder.viewDetailTextView.setOnClickListener(viewDetailSelectedListener);

    holder.videoCallTextView.setId(i);
    holder.videoCallTextView.setOnClickListener(videoCallSelectedListener);

    holder.phoneCallTextView.setId(i);
    holder.phoneCallTextView.setOnClickListener(phoneCallSelectedListener);

    return convertView;
}

View.OnClickListener viewDetailSelectedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            int index = (Integer) v.getId();
            itemClickListener.itemClickedAtIndex(index, "00");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

View.OnClickListener videoCallSelectedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            int index = (Integer) v.getId();
            if (screen == 2) {
                itemClickListener.itemClickedAtIndex(index, "33");
            } else {
                itemClickListener.itemClickedAtIndex(index, "11");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};

View.OnClickListener phoneCallSelectedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            int index = (Integer) v.getId();
            itemClickListener.itemClickedAtIndex(index, "22");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};

}
```